# string' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Tags: c#, string, linq

I'm having trouble creating a successful LINQ statement for an assignment. I keep getting the same error: 'string' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've edited the LINQ statement a few times, I've looked up some examples as well. Maybe it's just a lack of understanding but I'm continuing to get the same error with the "UppercaseWords" statements I'm writing. After trying most of the things I've gathered looking up the error, I figured the next best thing is to just ask myself.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Configuration;

namespace Assignment6
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string UserInput;
            List<string> ListOfWords = new List<string>();
            ListOfWords.Add("");


            Console.Write("   Enter First Name:       ");
            UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            ListOfWords.Add(UserInput);

            Console.Write("   Enter Last Name:       ");
            UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            ListOfWords.Add(UserInput);

            Console.Write("   Enter Street:       ");
            UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            ListOfWords.Add(UserInput);

            Console.Write("   Enter City:       ");
            UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            ListOfWords.Add(UserInput);

            Console.Write("   Enter State:       ");
            UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            ListOfWords.Add(UserInput);

            Console.Write("   Enter Zip:       ");
            UserInput = Console.ReadLine();
            ListOfWords.Add(UserInput);


            var ProcessedOut =
                from word in ListOfWords
                let uppercaseString = word.UppercaseWords()
                select uppercaseString;

            foreach (var word in ProcessedOut)
                Console.Write("{0}", word);

            Console.WriteLine();

        }


        //string being passed in is a word or phrase
        public static string UppercaseWords(string value)

        {
            //make an array from character in word 
            //takes each letter from the word to create an array element 
            char[] array = value.ToCharArray();

            if (array.Length >= 1)
            {
                if (char.IsLower(array[0]))
                {
                    array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i - 1] == ' ')
                {
                    if (char.IsLower(array[i]))
                    {
                        array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return new string(array);
        }




    }
```

I'm expected to have each piece of data in the output return with a capital letter at the beginning of every word.

All of the code under "public static string UppercaseWords(string value)" I have to include for the assignment.

Thank you in advance for anyone who can help.

Comment: Your functions is not properly defined as an extension method. Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)?

Comment: See marked duplicate for an example of syntax for an extension method declared for a `string` value. Or, just **read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)**

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make an Extension method you need to do something like this

```
public static class Word
{
    //string being passed in is a word or phrase
    public static string UppercaseWords(this string value)
    {
        //make an array from character in word 
        //takes each letter from the word to create an array element 
        char[] array = value.ToCharArray();

        if (array.Length >= 1)
        {
            if (char.IsLower(array[0]))
            {
                array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i - 1] == ' ')
            {
                if (char.IsLower(array[i]))
                {
                    array[i] = char.ToUpper(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return new string(array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `UpperCaseWords()` on `word` so it'll be looking for that method in the default `string` methods library (see "Methods" section of the sidebar in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8)).

Your method isn't extending the `string` class (adding your own method to `string`'s library) and it's declared as `static`, so you can simply call it like this:

```
var ProcessedOut =
    from word in ListOfWords
    let uppercaseString = UppercaseWords(word)
    select uppercaseString;
```

`static` means the method belongs to itself rather than a specific object instance so it can be called independently (as above), and in your case it's expecting a string as a parameter, so we give it `word`.